# Kolmogorov-Smirnov test in Grafana

Tags: statistics, grafana

When reading through the DevOps Handbook by Gene Kim, I came across this interesting tid bit of information -

[image]

Apparently there is native functionality within Grafana that allows you to perform the K-S test on different datasets. Looking through the documentation I haven't been able to find anything confirming this.

Does anyone know how to perform this test on datasets? Do I need to do it within a query as a function, or is it something simpler that I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Grafana don't do a lot of computation so could be Graphite instead. Nothing in Grafana and Graphite docs about it. I doubt it's true.